# How to manage and skip exceptions properly? And phonenumbers lib to cover)

Tags: python, exception, python-phonenumber

I use https://github.com/daviddrysdale/python-phonenumbers in my project to fix all bad numbers.

```
import csv
import phonenumbers

with open('base.csv') as f:
    data = list(csv.reader(f, delimiter=';'))

header_row = data[0]
header_row[8] = "Fixed Home Phone"
header_row[13] = "Fixed Mobile Phone"


for row in data[1:6]:  # we go from first because there is header row
    try:
        print(f'Original row - {row[7]}')
        x = phonenumbers.parse(row[7], "RU") #LOOK HERE! sometimes exception, due to blank field
        print(x)
        num2 = phonenumbers.parse(row[12], "RU")
        print(f'Phone Num Script Response - {num2}')  # sometimes exception is here
        print("To national format - ", phonenumbers.format_number(x, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164))
        row[8] = phonenumbers.format_number(x, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)
        row[13] = phonenumbers.format_number(y, phonenumbers.PhoneNumberFormat.E164)
    except:
          continue
        

writer = csv.writer(open("base_new.csv", 'w'))
for row in data:
    writer.writerow(row)
```

Some rows in comment "#LOOK HERE!" -in code are empty in my file.
So this library phone numbers throws an exception. And i am struggling with fixing it.

Here is the example of exception from their page

```
>>> z = phonenumbers.parse("02081234567", None)  # no region, no + => unparseable
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.py", line 2350, in parse
    "Missing or invalid default region.")
phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException: (0) Missing or invalid default region.
>>> z = phonenumbers.parse("gibberish", None)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "phonenumbers/phonenumberutil.py", line 2344, in parse
    "The string supplied did not seem to be a phone number.")
phonenumbers.phonenumberutil.NumberParseException: (1) The string supplied did not seem to be a phone number.
```

So(because i wanted program to still work through wrong numbers, i made TRY/Except and added continue.
But it turned our that either variable x gives exception and num2 is skipped, or vice versa) It is such a struggle for me.

Please advise, how can handle exceptions properly and what to add, so my script could Fix both x AND num2 in EVERY row?

Answer (score 0):

Your exception handlers should be just around the `x = phonenumbers.parse` and `num= = phonenumbers.parse`. When an exception is caught, simply set `x` or `num` to your desired alternative value.

Comment: Is it a good practice to copy big part of code(process the second nubber and parsing) to exception, if exception is caught with first number? Is there any other way? Like GO-TO-Line23 form here))

Comment: @BogdanMind: There's no need to copy code. The `except` for `x` ends before the normal code of `num2`. When an exception is successfully handled, normal execution continues. on the first line after the `except`.

Comment: Thank you for clarification, but i still don’t get it. Now i have continue in except. Why isn’t it working with second number when the first is missing?

Comment: @BogdanMind: You don't need a `continue`. That continues the **loop** with the next row, skipping the remainder of the current row.

Comment: Sorry if it is stupid simple), but should i just remove “continue”? It doesn’t work this way(